# Wrong textbook answer for determining solutions to a matrix equation using Cramer rule?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have spent the last 80 minutes on this question and it's frustrating because it should be super simple. For reference, the textbook is Linear Algebra and Its Applications 6th edition by David Lay.

**Question**

Determine the values of the parameters for which the system has a unique solution, and describe the solution:
\begin{eqnarray}
2sx_1 + 5x_2 &=& 8\\
6x_1 + 3sx_2 &=& 4
\end{eqnarray}
**Provided answer by the textbook**
$$
s \ne\pm \sqrt{5}
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x_1 &=& {12s + 10 \over 3(s^2 - 5)}\\
x_2 &=& {-4s-24 \over 3(s^2 - 5)}
\end{eqnarray}
**My attempt and issue**

To solve this question I used Cramer's rule. My answer is almost similar to the textbook one, but my positive/negative signs are slightly different:
$$
s \ne\pm \sqrt{5}
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x_1 &=& {12s - 10 \over 3(s^2 - 5)}\\
x_2 &=& {4s-24 \over 3(s^2 - 5)}
\end{eqnarray}

I just don't understand how the textbook manages to get the respective numerator for $x_1$ (how can it have a positive sign?!) and then the numerator of $x_2$ is messed up as well?!

Comment: [WolframAlpha gives your solution.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve%5B%7B2s+x+%2B+5+y+%3D%3D+8%2C+6+x+%2B+3+s+y+%3D%3D+4%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%7D%5D) It's possible the book has an error, or you have copied something wrong. For example, the book solution is consistent with the second equation having $-4$ instead of $4$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thanks so much for your reply! The WolframAlpha link does clear it up and as far as I can see (I have checked multiple times), I did indeed copy the equation correctly. I think this was indeed a typo from the author. Would it be a good idea to message them about this?

Comment: Good news! You're absolutely right. It just wasted your time, been there...

Comment: If this is a print textbook (or not easily correctable format for an online book), you might see if you can find a list of errata for it, and see if the issue is mentioned. If so, there is no reason to tell them about an issue they already know.